# How to execute a program on remote machine from Cruise Control .net build process?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I want to run a tool as part of my build process which requires environment setup for its execution. I have setup this environment on another machine. Is there any way I can execute the program on the remote machine from my cruise control .net build process. I know how to run the tools on the same machine. but I am not able to figure out how can i execute it if this tool is on remote machine. Any suggestions?

Comment: do you want to execute an exe on a remote machine.?

Comment: Yes, I want to execute exe with bunch of parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to remotely call a command-line tool on another machine.